# Max Mega Menu white triangle on top of submenu

Tags: css, wordpress

i would like to create a white triangle on top of the submenu of the Max Mega Menu (the WordPress plugin: https://www.megamenu.com/ It has a live version on the page)

Here is an example of a submenu with the white triangle: https://gridscale.io/

I'm having problems with selection the correct class of the submenu to make the triangle on top if it.

Does anyone have a simple snippet to add a white triangle on top of the submenu?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you want that white stripe, i.e. above the menu.
For this, you need to edit your CSS file and adding the padding at the top of navg bar!

Like:

```
.top-nav {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```